# Why does IPAddress.IsLoopback return true for an entire range of IPv4 addresses?

Tags: .net, ip-address

The .Net documentation states that the [IPAddress.IsLoopback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.isloopback(v=vs.110).aspx) method, for IPv4, "returns true for any IP address of the form 127.X.Y.Z (where X, Y, and Z are in the range 0-255), not just Loopback (127.0.0.1)."

Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: Because they ARE loopback addresses.  Try any of them and you will see they all point back to your local machine.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - Although, certain OSs don't support that out of the box; I'm not sure if the RFCs that specify host behavior require that *every* loopback address be configured, just that those are the addresses that can be used for loopback. Trying any of them *on windows* will work, but not on, eg, FreeBSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [RFC 6890](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6890) (page 6) and also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Loopback) entry. The last 3 octects from 0-255 are reserved as loopback addresses.